# Why are group boxes, being static, a type of Button control?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, controls

Just out of curiosity,

The Win32 Group Box control is actually a Button control with the style `BS_GROUPBOX` applied. As the control is static, being simply text with a special border, why is it one of the Button styles, when the rest are all for actual buttons or button-like UI elements which receive user input?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes *way* back to the 1980s.  Everybody that worked on it is drinking pina coladas in Hawai today so we'll have to make-do with a guess.  The likely one is that, since it was so very important to minimize the foot-print of Windows back then, that the existing plumbing for the BUTTON control was re-usable to implement a group box as well.